How do I create a container for an android app emulation
I would like to launch several instances of an android emulator to use an app, is there an option to create a very minimalistic android VM or something similar for use in docker to save on resources needed?
So, i've thought of using adb built-in emulator, but it's pretty resource heavy, maybe using very basic.
Maybe a docker container with barebone linux with something like anbox?
Thanks in advance
